# How to assign and manipulate Qiskit's TwoLocal ParameterVector?

Tags: qiskit, programming, machine-learning

Below is my code in python where i just show Qiskit's TwoLocal variational circuit model.

```
from qiskit.circuit.library import TwoLocal

n_qubits = 3
n_layers = 2
circuit = TwoLocal(n_qubits, 'ry', 'cx', 'linear', reps=n_layers, insert_barriers=True)

print("Circuit\n: {}".format(circuit.decompose().draw()))
```

My doubt is: is there any way to describe this ParameterVector $\theta$? Assigning values to each $\theta [i]$ for example.
I looked in the documentation of this Ansatz but apparently all the methods are for showing the parameters. Not to modify them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [`QuantumCircuit.assign_parameters`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.assign_parameters.html) method in Qiskit docs.

The simplest way to assign numerical values to each $\theta[i]$ in your parameter vector $\theta$ is to call `assign_parameters` passing an array-like object (values are bounded to parameters in alphabetical order):

```
import numpy as np

num_pars = len(circuit.parameters)
values = np.random.rand(num_pars)
new_circuit = circuit.assign_parameters(values)
```

Comment: It worked out! Thank you